# Using GROUP_CONCAT on subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, mysql-error-1242

I have a MySQL query in which I want to include a list of ID's from another table. On the website, people are able to add certain items, and people can then add those items to their favourites. I basically want to get the list of ID's of people who have favourited that item (this is a bit simplified, but this is what it boils down to).

Basically, I do something like this:

```
SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT userid FROM favourites WHERE itemid = items.id) SEPARATOR ',') AS idlist
FROM items
WHERE id = $someid
```

This way, I would be able to show who favourited some item, by splitting the idlist later on to an array in PHP further on in my code, however I am getting the following MySQL error:

> *1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row*

I thought that was kind of the point of using `GROUP_CONCAT` instead of, for example, `CONCAT`? Am I going about this the wrong way?

---

Ok, thanks for the answers so far, that seems to work. However, there is a catch. Items are also considered to be a favourite if it was added by that user. So I would need an additional check to check if creator = userid. Can someone help me come up with a smart (and hopefully efficient) way to do this?

Thank you!

Edit: I just tried to do this:

```
SELECT [...] LEFT JOIN favourites ON (userid = itemid OR creator = userid)
```

And **idlist** is empty. Note that if I use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` I get an empty result. Even though I am sure there are rows that meet the ON requirement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't access variables in the outer scope in such queries (can't use `items.id` there). You should rather try something like

```
SELECT
    items.name,
    items.color,
    CONCAT(favourites.userid) as idlist
FROM
    items
INNER JOIN favourites ON items.id = favourites.itemid
WHERE
    items.id = $someid
GROUP BY
    items.name,
    items.color;
```

Expand the list of fields as needed (name, color...).

Comment: This might have changed as i can use `AS` command to set your rows as variables then you can access them from any scope as i do quite frequently E.G 
SELECT `*`,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `blog_likes` WHERE `blog_id` = B.`blog_id` ) AS likes FROM blog AS B

Answer (score 136):

OP almost got it right. `GROUP_CONCAT` should be wrapping the columns in the subquery and not the [complete subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455991/838733) (I'm dismissing the separator because comma is the default):

```
SELECT i.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userid) FROM favourites f WHERE f.itemid = i.id) AS idlist
FROM items i
WHERE i.id = $someid
```

This will yield the desired result and also means that the accepted answer is partially wrong, because you can access outer scope variables in a subquery.

Comment: nice one, I was doing the same thing and putting the GROUP_CONCAT outside the sub query, thanks for the help!!

Comment: if I would a moderator, I would make this answer best, instead of accepted one

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev That's what upvotes are for on this platform. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have the "userid = itemid" wrong, shouldn't it be like this:

```
SELECT ITEMS.id,GROUP_CONCAT(FAVOURITES.UserId) AS IdList
FROM FAVOURITES 
INNER JOIN ITEMS ON (ITEMS.Id = FAVOURITES.ItemId OR FAVOURITES.UserId = ITEMS.Creator)
WHERE ITEMS.Id = $someid
GROUP BY ITEMS.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of GROUP_CONCAT is correct but the subquery is unnecessary and causing the problem. Try this instead:

```
SELECT ITEMS.id,GROUP_CONCAT(FAVOURITES.UserId)
FROM FAVOURITES INNER JOIN ITEMS ON ITEMS.Id = FAVOURITES.ItemId
WHERE ITEMS.Id = $someid
GROUP BY ITEMS.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, soulmerge's solution is ok. But I needed a query where I had to collect data from more child tables, for example:

- main table: **sessions** (presentation sessions) (uid, name, ..)
- 1st child table: **events** with key session_id (uid, session_uid, date, time_start, time_end)
- 2nd child table: **accessories_needed** (laptop, projector, microphones, etc.) with key session_id (uid, session_uid, accessory_name)
- 3rd child table: **session_presenters** (presenter persons) with key session_id (uid, session_uid, presenter_name, address...)

Every Session has more rows in child tables tables (more time schedules, more accessories)

And I needed to collect in one collection for every session to display in ore row (some of them):

```
session_id | session_name | date | time_start | time_end | accessories | presenters
```

My solution (after many hours of experiments):

```
SELECT sessions.uid, sessions.name,
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `events`.date SEPARATOR '</li><li>') 
            FROM `events` 
            WHERE `events`.session_id = sessions.uid ORDER BY `events`.date) AS date
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `events`.time_start SEPARATOR '</li><li>') 
            FROM `events` 
            WHERE `events`.session_id = sessions.uid ORDER BY `events`.date) AS time_start
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `events`.time_end SEPARATOR '</li><li>') 
            FROM `events` 
            WHERE `events`.session_id = sessions.uid ORDER BY `events`.date) AS time_end
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( accessories.name SEPARATOR '</li><li>') 
            FROM accessories 
            WHERE accessories.session_id = sessions.uid ORDER BY accessories.name) AS accessories
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( presenters.name SEPARATOR '</li><li>') 
            FROM presenters
            WHERE presenters.session_id = sessions.uid ORDER BY presenters.name) AS presenters

    FROM sessions
```

So no JOIN or GROUP BY needed. 
Another useful thing to display data friendly (when "echoing" them):

- you can wrap the events.date, time_start, time_end, etc in "<UL><LI> ... </LI></UL>" so the "<LI></LI>" used as separator in the query will separate the results in list items.

I hope this helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: Regardless of what you are trying to accomplish - you are mixing storage and view layer here. You should never use the database to prepare HTML output, you are mixing layers and this is really hard to maintain:-\

Comment: Maintainability is one aspect, but other is performance. '<li>'-elements can be added server-side or client-side. The worst choice regarding performance is to fetch large array of rows, add '<li>'-elements using server-side language eg. PHP, because you have to traverse array in PHP just to get those '<li>'-elements in right place. So it is better to drop PHP and generate the string in MYSQL. But the BEST choice is to generate a serialized javascript array/object of actual data using GROUP_CONCAT and add those <li>:s client-side. The client is usually the one who needs those '<li>'.