# Database Normalization on LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join, database-normalization

I wanted to load all my post tags with a single query into the MySQL server.
Now, I have decided to use LEFT JOIN because if there is no tags are associated with my post then also I will have that post, or you have any other suggestion for this?
Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tags, tags_map 
LEFT JOIN posts on posts.cid = tags_map.pid 
WHERE tags.tag_id = tags_map.tid
```

Now the problem is duplicate data, for example if a post has three tags then the post itself will repeat three time! 
In this case should I run another query for each post to have their tags? or can i get them all with a single query but without duplicate data?

Comment: Provide the DDL of the tables.

Comment: pls provide what result you get from your sql .

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455958/mysql-group-concat-with-left-join)

```
SELECT posts.*, 
   (select GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name)
    from  tags, 
      tags_map 
LEFT JOIN  on posts.cid = tags_map.pid 
WHERE tags.tag_id = tags_map.tid) as tagCombo
from posts
```

If you post a schema, sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQLFiddle, I can check.